Cargo Lambda not recognizing Axum Routes
I am using Cargo Lambda and Axum to make a REST API. Here is my main.rs file:
use axum::extract::Query;
use axum::http::StatusCode;
use axum::{
    extract::Path,
    response::Json,
    routing::{get, post},
    Router,
};
use lambda_http::{run, Error};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{json, Value};
use std::env::set_var;
use tower::ServiceBuilder;

mod controllers;
mod models;
mod middlewares;

/// Example on how to return status codes and data from an Axum function
async fn health_check() -> (StatusCode, String) {
    let health = true;
    match health {
        true => (StatusCode::OK, "Healthy!".to_string()),
        false => (
            StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            "Not healthy!".to_string(),
        ),
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    // If you use API Gateway stages, the Rust Runtime will include the stage name
    // as part of the path that your application receives.
    // Setting the following environment variable, you can remove the stage from the path.
    // This variable only applies to API Gateway stages,
    // you can remove it if you don't use them.
    // i.e with: `GET /test-stage/todo/id/123` without: `GET /todo/id/123`
    set_var("AWS_LAMBDA_HTTP_IGNORE_STAGE_IN_PATH", "true");

    // required to enable CloudWatch error logging by the runtime
    // tracing::init_default_subscriber();

    let mongo_uri =
        std::env::var("mongodb+srv://ashwin:ashwin@cluster0.fmupqcr.mongodb.net/raffy").unwrap_or_else(|_| "mongodb://localhost:27017".to_string());

    controllers::db::initialize_mongo_client(&mongo_uri).await?;

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/rushee/signup", post(controllers::rushee::signup))
        .route("/rushee/get-rushees", get(controllers::rushee::get_rushees))
        .route("/rushee/:id", get(controllers::rushee::get_rushee))
        .route(
            "/rushee/post-comment/:id",
            post(controllers::rushee::post_comment),
        )
        .route("/rushee/post-pis/:id", post(controllers::rushee::post_pis))
        .route(
            "/rushee/update-attendance/:id",
            post(controllers::rushee::update_attendance),
        )
        .route(
            "/rushee/update-cloud/:id",
            post(controllers::rushee::update_cloud),
        )
        .route(
            "/rushee/update-rushee/:id",
            post(controllers::rushee::update_rushee),
        )
        .route(
            "/rushee/reschedule-pis/:id",
            post(controllers::rushee::reschedule_pis),
        );

    run(app).await

}

I ran cargo lambda watch, and if I run any request, the following error shows up:
{"detail":"that function doesn't exist as a binary in your project. Available functions: {\"server\"}","title":"Missing function"}
I am confused as to why this is happening. I even tried the example on the aws-labs github, and got the same issue. Do I need to manually add the functions somewhere? Any help is greatly apprieciated!
EDIT: When i change the route for any function to "/", it works perfectly fine.
